# Buzzer circuit problem in Proteus

Tags: proteus, piezo-buzzer, pic16f877a

[image: proteus]

In this circuit, the buzzer should sound when the button is pressed.

```
    #include <buzzer.h>
    
    #INT_EXT
    void  EXT_isr(void) 
    {
       output_high(pin_c7);
       delay_ms(3000);
       output_low(pin_c7);
    }
    
    void main()
    {
       ext_int_edge(H_to_L);
       enable_interrupts(INT_EXT);
       enable_interrupts(GLOBAL);
    
       while(TRUE)
       {
           //TODO: User Code
       }
   }
```

I wrote this code but the buzzer does not sound.

How can I run the circuit without changing the circuit design?

Comment: If the buzzer is designed to run on 24 volts, it should be between the R3 and and Q1 collector.  As it is, the transistor is operating as an emitter follower, so the voltage across the buzzer will be about 4.3 volts, if Vcc for the processor is 5 volts.

Comment: I know the buzzer must be between R3 and Q1 but this is the circuit. VCC appears to be 5V. Buzzer operating voltage is 12V, it doesn't work even though I change the voltage. Is it possible to solve the problem by making changes in the codes?

Comment: As I said, Q1 is used as an emitter follower.  In an NPN emitter follower, the emitter voltage will always be about 0.7 volts below the base voltage.  If Vcc for the processor is 5 volts, a 5 volt buzzer should work.  A 12 volt buzzer MUST go between Q1 collector and a +12 volts supply (or maybe 24 volts and a suitable resistor). You have a haradware problem here - it can't be fixed in software.

Comment: *without changing the circuit design?* **You can't, no one can.** The buzzer is getting only a few volts due to the way you connected it in combination with the NPN (Q1). You made an "emitter follower" which doesn't behave like a switch. Remove the buzzer and connect it in series with R3. Also connect the emitter of Q1 to ground.

Comment: Your main problem is lack of design specs and datasheet for buzzer

Answer (score 1):

A passive piezoelectric buzzer is a capacitor. It will never work on DC voltage. Neither 5V nor 24V. The AC voltage must be controlled from two outputs by push-pull control. Or do the same with an external inverter. The frequency must match the value specified for the beep (eg. 3 kHz). An active (eg. electromechanical) buzzer requires a supply voltage.  First, the type of buzzer should be clarified for a solution.